# Create new LiDAR raster with levels above line height in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, analysis

I have a LiDAR raster file and a line with river levels. I'm wondering if there is a way to do some analysis to essentially find bank tops in the LiDAR data that are below a certain level in the line attributes. I want to be able to highlight or create a new shapefile that shows where the low spots are and by how much compared to the target level in the line attribute.

There would have to be a bandwidth either side of the line of about 50m. I've tried converting the line to polygon but this doesn't create the required 'rectangles' as there a lots of vertices etc.

I'm a complete novice.

Lidar with line shapefile

[image: LIDAR with the line shapefile]

What i end up with when convert line to polygon
[image]

Comment: Hi Gareth Lewis, welcome to GIS SE. Could you at screenshots of your data and of the (so far not working) solution? This would be very helpful to understand what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, which means you have to provide the problem, not just a description of the task, to get assistance. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate what you have tried.

Comment: Hi, i've added some screen shots

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what you are after. For example, the raster being "below a certain level in the line attributes" - what level, and along which section of the line? Does the level vary along the line? Consider (manually) drawing on your screenshots if needed, and attaching links to actual data. If you need a 50m buffer along your line, try the Buffer tool to start with.